# ASP Content Images not working

Tags: asp.net, image

:(

Images are showing up fine when local:

[image]

but when I upload it to my server it doesn't like the link?

[live demo](http://completesweets.azurewebsites.net/products)

I saw some SO's that had similar problems and was told to `"img src="~/..."` but that's not working.

Here's my code:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images_fixed/@(item.link).scale_20.jpg" width=" 190" height="130" />
```

here's my content folder:

[image: content folder]

It shows "nothing" in folder but if I click 'show all' i see the images. All the images are in the folder as well so that's not the error (as you can see they load fine locally)

**EDIT**

you will see the images working on my server but that's only because I am using this
`<img src="http://www.jdmdev.net/sweetscomplete/images/@(item.link).scale_20.JPG" />`

instead of `<img src="~/Content/Images_fixed/@(item.link).scale_20.jpg" />` So my problem is still here it is not solved for some reason when you upload to your project it doesn't use same links, or possibly the images don't get uploaded(even though they appear on github just fine).

**RESOLUTION**

The cause: When you import images in visual studio, you need to 'include in project'. It will work locally, but once you put it on a live server it will no longer see the images. You must include in project, re-open visual studio and update your SVN that your server is retrieving the build from.

Comment: i think your path is incorrect `95_2542284.scale_20.jpg` please remove the `.scale` something like `95_2542284_scale_20.jpg`

Comment: that has nothing to do with it, I have it working on my PHP version (www.jdmdev.net/sweetscomplete/products.php) however I tried just for the hell of it, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include these images in your project, then try to publish your site. Maybe they are not uploading onto your server.

UPDATE:
If you 'Show All Files' in your project in Visual Studio, and then 'Include in Project' all your images, then they will be added to .csproj file. Then you can commit your changes to github (including the .csproj file) and allow Azure to build your project and upload the files to your server.

Comment: Well my Azure server is actually grabbing the solution from github, link is here: https://github.com/jordmax12/SweetsCompleteASP, if you check Content/Images_fixed they are there.

Comment: In your github project the path is Images but your link had Images_fixed. I see you fixed it just now.

Comment: What? Link was always Images_fixed. I have 2 folders in Content, 1 is Images which isn't being called at all (folder issues in visual studio, so made a new one the right way named 'Images_fixed' and was using that). I didn't change it since I posted on here though.

Comment: I don't know how that is possible because before answering to you images weren't working, but now they are.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining that. They are working because I am using an outside source to grab the links : `<img src="http://www.jdmdev.net/sweetscomplete/images/@(item.link).scale_20.JPG" />` instead of `<img src="~/Content/Images_fixed/@(item.link).scale_20.jpg" />`

Comment: Yes, you can have them on your github, but these images should be included in .csproj, like this: <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.js" /> so the Azure knows which files to upload to your server

Comment: hmm ok where do i put that then? .csproj? is that the .cshtml?

Comment: oh man. i thoguht for sure this would work. it made so much sense, but not working :(.

Comment: are you sure you included the images in the project and committed your changes to repository? i don't see the changes

Comment: did a couple commits to try different things, I did add to project, and I am working out of my github folder so it will automatically update it. here's commit though I'm assuming the cache thing is the 'include in project', unless I am wrong... https://github.com/jordmax12/SweetsCompleteASP/commit/41d25d8ce2d00c56f449223ebe5ef31513c04ffc

Comment: that's .cshtml which is different from .csproj. This file should be committed (if you have done what is suggested in answer): https://github.com/jordmax12/SweetsCompleteASP/blob/master/SweetsCompleteApp/SweetsCompleteApp.csproj

Comment: looks like i had to re-open visual studio for github to recognize changes. looks like it's working now! thank you.